# Adding an array of strings into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I need to add an array of strings, into a two dimensional array called squares. The array squares is a 10 by 10 array in which the first row of initStrings will match up with squares.

IE - `static String[] strings = {"hello"}`

The `h` would be in the first location of the squares array, the `e` would be in the second and so on. Im wondering how to do this.

```
static String[] initStrings =
        {
         "...../...\\",
         "..\\.......",
         "......./..",
         "..........",
         "........\\.",
         "..........",
         "..........",
         ".....\\../.",
         "..\\....../",
         ".........."
        };
```

I know that I need to have a nested for loop. Something along the lines of

```
for (col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {

            for (rows = 0; rows < 10; rows ++)
            {
                // what goes here?
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to convert an array of strings into a 2d array of characters?

Comment: What is squares a char array?

Comment: I'm also unsure of what your final requirement is, but I posted some code below it might help. Thanks

Comment: Instead of re-posting the same question, I would suggest responding to people asking for clarification of your issue. Posting the same question again with no additional information doesn't make it any easier to find your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
static String[] initStrings = { "...../...\", "..\.......", "......./..", "..........", "........\.", "..........", "..........", ".....\../.", "..\....../", ".........." };
char[][] squares = new char[10][10];
int row, col;

for (row = 0; row < 10; rows ++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 10; col++)
    {
        squares[row][col] = initStrings[row].charAt(col);
    }
}

// print squares
for (row = 0; row < 10; rows ++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 10; col++)
    {
        System.out.print(squares[row][col] + " ");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you much it works great. Ill probably use your help again lol.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
    char[][] squares=new char[10][10];
    String[] initStrings = { "...../....", "../.......", "......./..", "..........",    "......../.", "..........", "..........", "...../../.", "../....../", ".........." };

    int i=0;
    for(char[] squareRow:squares)
        squareRow=initStrings[i++].toCharArray();
```

Comment: Well i needed it to be a nested for loop, but yeah I do believe that that would work the same way thank you

Comment: am slightly curious though..why nested loops?java supports for each from 1.6+..

Comment: Its just a class assignment. Unfortunately its what my teacher wants even though he knows there are easier ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution. It's a bit overkill, but I like maps, and lists :) One advantage with this is that if you add a new string to your initStrings with more than 10 chars, it should still finish. But, maybe that would be bad...

```
        String[] initStrings = {"...../...\\", "..\\.......",  "......./..",  "..........",  "........\\.",  "..........",  "..........", ".....\\../.", "..\\....../",  ".........."   };

        Map<Integer, List<String>> columnEntries = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();

        for(String str : initStrings) {
            for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if(!columnEntries.containsKey(i)) {
                    columnEntries.put(i, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                columnEntries.get(i).add(str.substring(i,i+1));
            }       
        }

        //Print results...                 
        for(Entry<Integer, List<String>> e : columnEntries.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey());         
            System.out.println(e.getValue());
        }
```